# Find last two non-NaN unique observations in a matrix per column

Tags: matlab, find, unique

I have a matrix A and I want to find per column the last two non-NaN values.

For example, generate the following matrix:

```
A = [NaN, 3, NaN; 5  5  5; NaN  1  9;  4  1   4;  NaN  6   NaN;  6   2   9]
```

I want to get the following result:

```
B =

     4     6     4
     6     2     9
```

**How can I do this in the most efficient way, without a for-loop?**

---

I tried the following: `[row,col,v] = find(A,3,'last')`, but this returns something that I do not understand:

```
row =

     5
     6


col =

     3
     3


v =

   NaN
     9
```

Comment: Do you want unique values? If the last column has two consecutive same values. You will want only one of them. Right?

Comment: Correct. Yes unique

Comment: @rayryeng ^ :-/

Comment: @SardarUsama OK, I'm going to leave my answer. Not worth the effort since there's an accepted answer.  Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @rayryeng The answer was not working when there are no NaNs. So question is open again.

Comment: @JohnAndrews In that case, use `isnan` and check to see if there are any values that are `nan`.  If that isn't the case, then just crop the last two rows of your matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter of `find` actually finds the actual locations that are non-zero.  It searches on a column-wise basis and returns the row and column locations of the last three non-zero values and their actual values.  `NaN` is technically non-zero, which is why it is returned to you.

First start off with finding all locations that are not `NaN` in your matrix with `find`:

```
[I,J] = find(~isnan(A));
```

This will now return row and column locations of the values that were not `NaN`.  We now get:

```
>> [I,J]

ans =

     2     1
     4     1
     6     1
     1     2
     2     2
     3     2
     4     2
     5     2
     6     2
     2     3
     3     3
     4     3
     6     3
```

We can see a nice pattern forming.  The left column shows you all row locations that were not `NaN` and the right column tells you which column that was.

Next what we can do is for the second column, find the point where we transition from one column to another.  That will give us the locations of last element that was not `NaN` for each column.  We can then subtract these indices by 1 to give us the locations of the second last element that was not `NaN`.  We can use the [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function to help us do that and checking to see when the distance is non-zero.  Note that this will decrease the size of the output by 1 because we're computing pairwise distances, but simply pad a 1 at the end because this signifies the end of the last column and this is where we want to find the last two elements of the column:

```
>> d = [diff(J) ~= 0; 1];
>> [J d]

ans =

     1     0
     1     0
     1     1
     2     0
     2     0
     2     0
     2     0
     2     0
     2     1
     3     0
     3     0
     3     0
     3     1
```

Now let's take the output of `diff` and also shift everything up by 1:

```
d(1:end-1) = d(1:end-1) | d(2:end);
```

This will allow us to mark the second last element of each column to capture:

```
>> [I J d]

ans =

     2     1     0
     4     1     1
     6     1     1
     1     2     0
     2     2     0
     3     2     0
     4     2     0
     5     2     1
     6     2     1
     2     3     0
     3     3     0
     4     3     1
     6     3     1
```

Last but not least, we now sample the first two columns of the above matrix where the third column is non-zero, convert these into linear indices and sample our matrix.  We'll use a combination of [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) for that:

```
loc = d ~= 0;
out = reshape(A(sub2ind(size(A), I(loc), J(loc))), 2, size(A,2));
```

Thus:

```
>> out

out =

     4     6     4
     6     2     9
```

The final code is thus:

```
[I,J] = find(~isnan(A));
d = [diff(J) ~= 0; 1];
d(1:end-1) = d(1:end-1) | d(2:end);
loc = d ~= 0;
out = reshape(A(sub2ind(size(A), I(loc), J(loc))), 2, size(A,2));
```

## Warning

This assumes that you have at least two elements per column that are not `NaN`.

Comment: @SardarUsama That's right.  I was doing `accumarray`, then converted to this instead. It was a byproduct of not fixing the first part of the code.

Comment: Although OP's example doesn't depict any uniqueness, I am afraid that the OP may actually be wanting unique values in each column. (the edited out part of the question)

Comment: @SardarUsama That was only indicated in the title.  The actual question mentioned that he wanted the last two non-NaN values.  I took his question content to be what is correct and edited out the title.  If the OP really wants the last two unique values, then there is a risk that the output matrix would no longer be proper and you would have to resort to loops and cell arrays or perhaps `struct` because it's very possible to have a column that has non-NaN values, but only one unique value.

Comment: I totally agree with that

Comment: "This assumes that you have at least two elements per column that are not NaN". This is something that should be flexible. We don't know in advance if there will be if any NaNs.

Comment: @JohnAndrews If that's the case, then that's fine.  The code will automatically sample the last two rows so the code shouldn't change.  I'm not sure what your concern is.

Comment: If I want 3 obs, which param do I change?

Comment: @JohnAndrews OK, that will require a bit of re-engineering.... let me fix that up.

Comment: I get the message: To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Answer (score 2):

This is how:

```
A = [NaN, 3, NaN; 5  5  5; NaN  1  9;  4  1   4;  NaN  6   NaN;  6   2   9]
N=2; %last 2
IsOK=~isnan(A);
[~,I]=sort(IsOK);
Iok=I(end-N+1:end,:); %get last N
LinearIndxs=sub2ind(size(A), Iok, repmat(1:size(A,2),N,1));
Result=A(LinearIndxs)
```

Comment: I did check and it works for me. what is your input A?